# Strange border appears with a \fill with inner/outer color options

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading

I'd like to have a radial shaded circle whose outer color is the same as the background, but I didn't manage to do it.

If I set `outer color=white` without a background, a strange border appers (see Figure 1).

If I set the `outer color` equal to a background color, they are different in the output (see Figure 2).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \fill[even odd rule,inner color=red,outer color=white] (0,0) circle (3);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{How to get rid of the thin border here?}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \fill[cyan] (-4,-4) rectangle (4,4); 
            \fill[even odd rule,inner color=red,outer color=cyan] (0,0) circle (3);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{How to make the outer color equal to the background here?}     
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the two cases, you don't need to fill your circle before to shade it. So, use `\path` or `\shade` instead of `\fill`.

The second case uses colors from two different models: red (rgb) and cyan (hsv). But, with TikZ/pgf, shading always uses rgb colors. So, convert the `cyan` color to rgb before to use it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\colorlet{cyan}[rgb]{cyan}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \shade[even odd rule,inner color=red,outer color=white] (0,0) circle (3);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{How to get rid of the thin border here?}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \fill[cyan] (-4,-4) rectangle (4,4); 
            \path[even odd rule,inner color=red,outer color=cyan] (0,0) circle (3);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{How to make the outer color equal to the background here?}     
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]